# Is there a way to call the previous function used with the trim function to make a conditional?

Tags: python, loops, bioinformatics

I am translating DNA to Protein, or basically, referencing a table of values in a list and then calling the values in that list if certain conditions are met. However I am expected to now  use the "trim" function to write an extended version of the translate function from Question 1 called translate_trim that includes a boolean argument trim, which specifies if the function should trim their nucleotide sequence such that it is a multiple of three before attempting to translate it. The function should include all other functionalities specified in the code below

```
geneticcode = {
    'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
    'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
    'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
    'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
    'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
    'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
    'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
    'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
    'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
    'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
    'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
    'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
    'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
    'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
    'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_',
    'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W'
    }
```

```
def translate(seq):
    # Check if the length of the sequence is a multiple of three
    if len(seq) % 3 != 0:
        print("Please provide a sequence with a multiple of three")
        return None

    # Translate the DNA sequence to protein
    protein_sequence = ""
    for i in range(0, len(seq), 3):
        codon = seq[i:i+3]
        # Check if the codon is in the codon table
        if codon not in geneticcode:
            print("Invalid sequence, input sequence can only contain A, C, G, or T")
            return None
        amino_acid = geneticcode[codon]
        protein_sequence += amino_acid

    return protein_sequence
```

This is code I tried. They said there is a way to not have to recycle the code and only use trim but I dont know what is going wrong:

```
def translate_trim(seq, trim=True):
    bases = ('A','G','C','T')
# Check if the length of the sequence is a multiple of three
    if len(seq) % 3 != 0:
        print("Please provide a sequence with a multiple of three")
    if len(seq) not in bases:
        print ('Invalid sequence, input sequence can only contain A, C, G, or T')
        return none
    else:
        def translate(seq):
              return protein_sequence
```

Thank you!!

Comment: `geneticcode` is the `dict` from the first snippet.

Comment: a number of rookie errors:  `none` -> `None`,  `protein_sequence` is not defined...

Comment: @D.L please elaborate- I am new to this so I am not sure what the other issues are syntax wise either

Comment: ( @D.L: my assumption is that you duplicate some existing code and still never use the `trim` parameter.)

Comment: @quamrana:   i used (and modified) the code in the question and explained what i did...

Comment: @D.L, but that doesn't make it useful.

Comment: the OP has a fundamental issue calling the function, which is corrected. They can add the trim statement inside the `if` block in a meaningful way.

Comment: Also, your example call to `translate_trim()` never actually goes on to call `translate()`, so your modifications are not demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

To define `translate_trim`you need to :

1. Check if `seq`  contain characters from `bases`
2. Calculate the number of extra characters
3. If `trim` is True and there is extra characters remove this extra
4. Call `translate` and return the result

Here is updated code of `translate_trim`:

```
def translate_trim(seq, trim=True):
  bases = {'A', 'G', 'C', 'T'} 

  # 1 check if all elements in seq  are valid
  if not set(seq).issubset(bases):
    print('Invalid sequence, input sequence can only contain A, C, G, or T')
    return None

  #2 calculate the number of extra character to trim
  extra = len(seq) % 3

  #3 with -extra we can remove the last extra (the last 2 for example)
  if trim and (extra > 0):
    seq = seq[:-extra]

  #4 Translate using the translate function
  protein_sequence =  translate(seq)

  return protein_sequence
```

### Test :

Test with the animo acid sequence :

```
sequence ="ATGTACCACATAGTGATGGAGACGGAGCCATTGAAGCCGCCGGGCCCGCAGCAAACCTTCGGGGGGCGGCGGCGGCAACTCCACCGCGGCATTCGTTAGAT"
result = translate_trim(sequence)
print(result)
```

Output :

> MYHIVMETEPLKPPGPQQTFGGRRRQLHRGIR_

Comment: thank you so much @Hamza NABIL, this worked for me but I was wondering if you could explain a bit please what the logic is behind this so I understand please!

Comment: I updated the answer, please let me know if you have any specific question

Comment: @StarHopper: I still don't understand why the `bases` variable is part of the requirements.

Comment: to make sure `seq` contain only (A, C, G, or T) . for example if `seq=ACGTFA` it not valid because F is not in `bases`

Comment: If you believe that my answer is the best solution to your problem, can you kindly  accept it :)

Answer (score -1):

okay,  so actually you were quite close apart from:

- `none` -> `None`
- the function just needs to be called, since you have already defined it.

So the whole code might look like this:

```py
geneticcode = {
    'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
    'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
    'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
    'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
    'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
    'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
    'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
    'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
    'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
    'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
    'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
    'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
    'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
    'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
    'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_',
    'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W'
    }

def translate(seq):
    # Check if the length of the sequence is a multiple of three
    if len(seq) % 3 != 0:
        print("Please provide a sequence with a multiple of three")
        return None

    # Translate the DNA sequence to protein
    protein_sequence = ""
    for i in range(0, len(seq), 3):
        codon = seq[i:i+3]
        # Check if the codon is in the codon table
        if codon not in geneticcode:
            print("Invalid sequence, input sequence can only contain A, C, G, or T")
            return None
        amino_acid = geneticcode[codon]
        protein_sequence += amino_acid

    return protein_sequence


def translate_trim(seq, trim=True):
    bases = ('A','G','C','T')
    # Check if the length of the sequence is a multiple of three
    if trim:
        print('do some trimming')
        x = translate(seq)
    else:
        x = translate(seq)
        return x



result = translate_trim(geneticcode)

print(result)
```

The above game me this answer:

```
Please provide a sequence with a multiple of three
Invalid sequence, input sequence can only contain A, C, G, or T
None
```

I am not sure what you were looking for but the fundamental errors are fixed here.

Comment: ah thank you this is close but for some reaosn when I do a test such as: Test 3. This should return the amino acid string 'MYHIVMETEPLKPPGPQQTFGGRRRQLHRGIR_':
sequence ="ATGTACCACATAGTGATGGAGACGGAGCCATTGAAGCCGCCGGGCCCGCAGCAAACCTTCGGGGGGCGGCGGCGGCAACTCCACCGCGGCATTCGTTAGAT"
translate_trim(sequence, trim=True) it doesnt return the animo acid sequence

Comment: @StarHopper,  i modded the  `translate_trim` function to include an "example" of how you might call trim before invoking the translate function. . . .i leave the final bit of logi to you.

Comment: @StarHopper: You should really add that code to your question as a test code. Adding it now is an ambush on this answer.

Comment: @StarHopper.  i am leaving this question alone as it appears that i am being stalked for providing an answer and  help in good faith.

Comment: No not at all, this was extremely helpful, I am new and don't know better, I appreciate your help so much! @D.